# How do I make Chrome's autocomplete drop-down appear only after I begin typing (instead of on initial mouse click)?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, click, search-suggestion

Please help!

Recently (probably with version 66), Chrome began displaying its autocomplete-suggestion drop-down on the initial mouse click into a search field instead of waiting until a character is typed. 
How do I make Chrome go back to not displaying suggestions until I begin typing?

I have always made use of Chrome's suggestions drop-down for search fields, but I don't want or need to see a list of random suggestions just because I've clicked into an input field. I only want to see suggestions that match what I start to type (which is how it always worked until recently).

I tried disabling the "[Single-click autofill](http://chrome://flags/#enable-single-click-autofill)" flag and even the "[Show autofill predictions](http://chrome://flags/#show-autofill-type-predictions)" flag as well, but these flags don't seem to affect the situation. Perhaps the term *autofill* in these flags doesn't refer to the same thing?

If anyone can help me with this, I'll be your best friend forever and ever!

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue recently with a datepicker input. To get around it, I wrapped my inputs in a form and set autocomplete="off" in my form tag, as Chrome only recognizes that property for forms and not individual inputs. I added a keyup event so that if the input has text in it, autocomplete is re-enabled:

```
if (val.length > 0) {
    $('#myForm').attr('autocomplete', 'on');
} else {
    $('#myForm').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
}
```

You can also add an onBlur event to disable autocomplete suggestions each time you leave an input.